# NGRX - How can I access my app state in angular guard?

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I have a route guard(`canActivate`) and I need to access my app current state to validate a data to prevent users from invalid navigation. How can I get the current state?

I just tried to get the state using subscription on the store but it does not get the data unless the state is changed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this. Because canActivate expect you to return boolean value so you need to map your store data to boolean value

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable()
export class SomeGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {}

    loadData(): Observable<any> {
        return this.store.select(state => state.someState);
    }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.loadData()
            .pipe(switchMap(() => {
                return of(true);
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But your code in rxjs is deprecated and can be used by rxjs v<6. please change the use of `switchMap` and `of` operator.